# Is there a way to set DataTemplate for a control in an user control (a composite one) in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a composite user control containing a Toolbar and a Datagrid, and expose them as public properties. Is there a way to add new button to Toolbar and set a DataTemplate for Datagrid in XAML, instead of implementing them in the code-behind file if I use this user control in another Window or user control?

I found a similar link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991363/best-practices-of-building-composite-custom-controls-wpf), but has no idea how to do it. Please help.

Here is the Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CRUDDataGrid1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" >
        <ToolBar x:Name="tb">
            <Button x:Name="Add" Content="Add">                    
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dg">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class CRUDDataGrid1 : UserControl
{
    public ToolBar ToolBar { get; set; }
    public DataGrid DataGrid { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns { get; private set; } //edited

    public CRUDDataGrid1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToolBar = tb;
        DataGrid = dg;
        Columns = dg.Columns;  //edited
    }
}
```

And I want to use this user control in another user control like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1" ...>
<Grid>
    <local:CRUDDataGrid1>
        <local:CRUDDataGrid1.ToolBar>
            <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete">
            </Button>
        </local:CRUDDataGrid1.ToolBar>
        <local:CRUDDataGrid1.DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <local:CRUDDataGrid1.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@FirstName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@LastName}" />
            <local:CRUDDataGrid1.Columns>
        </local:CRUDDataGrid1.DataGrid>
    </local:CRUDDataGrid1>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Adding a button? Or defining a DataTemplate in XAML? Or assigning a DataTemplate in code-behind? Please also show some meaningful code so than we can get an understanding of what you try to achieve. As the saying goes: There are many ways to skin a cat...

Comment: Okay, i have a better picture now. First about the toolbar buttons. Essentially, you have a control with a toolbar (CRUDDataGrid1). You want to use this CRUDDataGrid1 in another control (UserControl1). And there in UserControl1, you want to define the buttons shown in the toolbar of CRUDDataGrid1, correct? Or do you want to merge the toolbar buttons defined in CRUDDataGrid1 with the buttons defined in UserControl1?

Comment: I want to merge the new buttons defined in UserControl1 with the existing buttons in Toolbar.

Comment: With regard to both CRUDDataGrid1 and UserControl1 (and in an attempt to understand the purpose of your handling of the *DataGrid*): Why do you not just declare the toolbar and the DataGrid in UserControl. There is no obvious benefit of having CRUDDataGrid1 - the XAML code in UserControl will be more or less the same with or without CRUDDataGrid1, and CRUDDataGrid1 also does not give you added function/flexibility as you insist to define almost everything in UserControl. CRUDDataGrid1 looks really redundant to me...

Comment: With respect to button merging: You can use just a single toolbar and initialize it with multiple (merged) lists of buttons in XAML. However, you will have to write a [IMultipleValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) which converts multiple lists of toolbar buttons (which can be declared in XAML) into a single list. Remember that a toolbar is just an **ItemsControl**, thus it has an *ItemsSource* property to which you can bind the button list to (use *<MultiBinding>* with the aforementioned converter).

Comment: Alternatively, to have cleaner XAML, you might also write your custom ToolBar class (inheriting from the standard ToolBar), implementing the merging of the button lists in code-behind (which would result in cleaner and better readable XAML without all that <MultiBinding> and converter stuff...)

Comment: I am building an application using MVVM pattern, and I want to reuse CRUDDataGrid1 in many Views with slight different buttons and ItemsSource (for DataGrid to display). Most functionalities are the same, that's the part I want to reuse.

Comment: I have no idea how to create a custom ToolBar to merge the button list, could you please give me a simple example? Thanks a lot. Besides, how about set DataTemplate for DataGrid? When I type '<local:CRUDDataGrid1.DataGrid>' in XAML, VS prompts that "This property has no value", how to solve it?

Comment: Regarding toolbar, i will provide you an example on weekend (unless someone is faster). Regarding CRUDDataGrid1.DataGrid see my previous comment: I really don't understand why you are doing that, in my opinion just get rid of that CRUDDataGrid1 control. Its only purpose is to establish the grid - which you could do as easily in UserControl1 and without all the headache and pain that caused you to write that question here at StackOverflow. Based on the code you have given, there is really no point for having that CRUDDataGrid1 control at all...

Comment: Yes, the code given is very simple. But the completed logic (the create, read, update and delete operations to manipulate DataGrid) in the code-behind is quite complicated (about 590 lines in total). If you want the completed source code, I can send them to you.

Comment: Ah, okay, i see. So, in reality you only want to modify certain properties of the DataGrid in UserControl1. Do you know about WPF styles? Just create a DependencyProperty CRUDDataGrid1 which will receive a Style object (for the DataGrid). In the XAML of CRUDDataGrid1, bind the DataGrid's **Style** property to that DependencyProperty. In UserControl1's XAML, you can alter DataGrid properties by defining a <Style> and assigning it to that DependencyProperty.

Comment: Yes, You're right, I can get rid of DataGrid control. But I still need the example of custom ToolBar. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: However, a Style does not work for Columns. Solution is however rather simple. Just expose the DataGrid's Columns property as a read-only ("get-only") property of CRUDDataGrid1, and then you can set this property in UserControl1's XAML in a similar way as <DataGrid.Columns>.

Comment: @elgonzo I've modified the code as above, but VS prompts that "the value of type "DataGridTextColumn" cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'ObservationCollection'", could you please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: How about chat? I am in Trillian (web-based, www.trillian.im/chat/) as user "gonzelmann".

Comment: Hi, are you in Trillian now?

Comment: Phew... answer given. Sorry that it took so long. And sorry that the answer is so long... Well, it is technically two answers... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 Foreword**

Having a child control which owns a *ToolBar* and wanting a parent of that child control to add toolbar items to the ToolBar owned by the child is a tell-tale sign of bad
design. The primary and most important advice for you is to rethink your software design to avoid this kind of shared/split initialization.

In almost any scenario, you want the toolbar owned by the top-most control such as the main window, or a document window (in case your application has MDI or floating windows).
The toolbar items would be gathered from the respective controls housed within that window; for example, copy/paste/etc. actions from the document editor control, actions for creating or loading a new document from somewhere else, etc.

Side note: Often, such a design happens because novice WPF programmers want to realize button actions in the old-fashioned way of using Click event handlers. Such Click-event
handlers create code dependencies, and as long as they can be contained within just one (custom) control everything is fine. However, as soon as this is not feasible any more
(for example when an action should appear as a toolbar button or the same action should be triggered through a menu), trying to stick with Click event handlers will lead to convoluted code even for simple UIs and can cause severe headache...

The mechanism in WPF to avoid those pesky Click event handlers are Commands, or more specifically [**RoutedCommands**](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/). To be fair, it has to be noted that *RoutedCommands* have their own
[share of challenges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx#id0190134). However, many fine folks wrote many interesting and important things about using WPF's *RoutedCommands* and how to expand beyond their functionality, so the
only sane advice i can give here is to use the powers of Google if you want/need to know more.

---

**2 Answering the question, but not solving the underlying design issue**

To create a *ToolBar* which has collections of toolbar items defined at different places, while using multiple toolbar bands in the same *ToolBarTray* is not desired, the toolbar item collections need to be merged into a single list at some point. This can either be done somehow in code-behind, or it can be done in XAML with the help of a custom [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

The custom *IMultiValueConverter* - let's call it **MergeCollectionsConverter** - will be
agnostic to any data type. It just takes a number of *IEnumerables* and adds all their elements to the result list. It even accepts objects which are not *IEnumerable*, those objects themselves will be added to the result list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace MyStuff
{
    public class MergeCollectionsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values == null) return null;

            List<object> combinedList = new List<object>();
            foreach (object o in values)
            {
                if (o is IEnumerable)
                    combinedList.AddRange( ((IEnumerable) o).Cast<object>() );
                else
                    combinedList.Add(o);
            }
            return combinedList;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I assume furthermore that the *ToolBar* inside of *CRUDDataGrid1* should be fed from two toolbar item collections. The first collection with the default toolbar items is defined within *CRUDDataGrid1*. The second collection should allow other controls to append additional toolbar items after the default items; this collection therefore has to be publicly accessible.

Based on your example code from the question, your CRUDDataGrid1 class could look like the following (just considering the toolbar, it does not represent the complete class by any means):

CRUDDataGrid1.cs:

```
public partial class CRUDDataGrid1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> AdditionalToolbarItems { get { return _additionalToolbarItems; } }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<object> _additionalToolbarItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _additionalToolbarItems.CollectionChanged +=
            (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AdditionalToolbarItems"));
            };

        ...other constructor code...
    }
}
```

CRUDDataGrid1.xaml:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar>
            <ToolBar.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type My:UseCommand}">
                    <Button
                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                        Command="{Binding Command}"
                        CommandTarget="{Binding Target}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter}"
                        Content="{Binding Command.Text}"
                    />
                </DataTemplate>

                <My:MergeCollectionsConverter x:Key="convToolbarItems" />

                <x:Array x:Key="defaultToolbarItems" Type="{x:Type sys:Object}">
                    <My:UseCommand Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
                    <My:UseCommand Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
                    <My:UseCommand Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
                </x:Array>
            </ToolBar.Resources>

            <ToolBar.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource convToolbarItems}">
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource defaultToolbarItems}" />
                    <Binding Path="AdditionalToolbarItems" ElementName="crudDataGrid1" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ToolBar.ItemsSource>

            </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" />
</DockPanel>
```

The first collection is a 'static resource' in the *ToolBar*'s resource directory,
identified by the resource key "**defaultToolbarItems**". The second is the collection provided by *CRUDDataGrid1*'s property **AdditionalToolbarItems**. Using a *<MultiBinding>*
with the aforementioned converter, the merged list is bound to the *ToolBar*'s *ItemsSource*.

Looking at the C# source code of the *AdditionalToolbarItems* property, you will notice the *INotifyPropertyChanged* implementation and the handler for the *CollectionChanged*
event. Why is that? Remember, that *AdditionalToolbarItems* is a read-only property. At the time the CRUDDataGrid1 control has been fully constructed, the data binding has been
set and *AdditionalToolbarItems* been processed by the multi binding. And it would never be
processed again, since the property itself will never change its value (it will
always refer to the same *ObservableCollection*). To make the *<MultiBinding>* re-evaluate the bound properties whenever the content of the *AdditionalToolbarItems* collection has
changed, the code needs to listen for *CollectionChanged* events and fire an
*PropertyChanged* event whenever the content of *AdditionalToolbarItems* has changed, which in turn will cause the <MultiBinding> to re-evaluate the bound properties.

You will also note the usage of **<My:UseCommand>** elements instead of using *<Button>*. Well, you could use *<Button>*, and it would work as well. Until your application wants to use multiple ToolBars at once sharing the same default buttons - in which case you have a problem: A button is a control and thus has **one** parent UI element. You cannot share
a button control amongst several toolbars, because a control can only be owned as a child by **one** parent UI element. Thus, *RoutedCommands* are used instead of button controls
(another, equally important reason will become obvious if you read the 'real' solution in section 3 below). Still, technically nothing would stop you from declaring *<Button>*
elements -- you could even mix *<My:UseCommand>* with *<Button>* (and other elements, as long as those can be rendered in the toolbar).

**UseCommand** is a pretty small and simple class which allows you to tell which command to use (plus optional *CommandTarget* and *CommandParameter*, if required):

```
namespace MyStuff
{
    public class UseCommand
    {
        public System.Windows.Input.ICommand Command { get; set; }
        public System.Windows.IInputElement Target { get; set; }
        public object Parameter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The ToolBar will need a *DataTemplate* to properly display the command and its parameters stored inside *UseCommand*. You can see this *DataTemplate* as part of the *ToolBar*
resource dictionary in the XAML code above.

With these things in place, using *CRUDDataGrid1* in **UserControl1** and adding additional toolbar items could look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1" ...>
    <Grid>
        <local:CRUDDataGrid1>
            <local:CRUDDataGrid1.AdditionalToolbarItems x:Name="cdg">
                <My:UseCommand Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=cdg}" />
                <My:UseCommand Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=cdg}" />
            </local:CRUDDataGrid1.AdditionalToolbarItems>
            ...
        </local:CRUDDataGrid1.DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

For my example code, i used commands provided by [System.Windows.Input.ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx). You can ofcourse roll your own commands (as we will see below). Also note the demonstrated usage of the *CommandTarget* property. Whether using this property is necessary requires some understanding of how RoutedCommands work and mostly depends on where which element in the UI's visual/logical tree has established handlers for that particular command.

---

**3 Using RoutedCommands to solve the design issue and the question**

Having read section 2, you should already gotten the idea that *RoutedCommands* will help you to separate the provision of user-invokable actions by whatever component from the actual UI representation, and that this can help you avoiding the shenanigans about the somewhat convoluted composition of the *ToolBar* from different sources. Because, all that *CRUDDataGrid1* essentially needs to provide for your GUI are the commands for a toolbar (or a menu, or any other command invokers for that matter).

From what i can glance from your source code, *CRUDDataGrid1* is responsible for executing the "**Add**" action, whereas *UserControl1* is responsible the "**Delete**" action.
Both actions should appear in the same toolbar.

Let's look at the "*Add*" action of *CRUDDataGrid1*. First and foremost, to make this action invokable through a *RoutedCommand*, an appropriate *RoutedCommand* object needs to be provided, obviously. You might choose one of the *RoutedCommands* provided by .NET (as declared in [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx), [ComponentCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.componentcommands.aspx) and [NavigationCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.navigationcommands.aspx)).
However, this is not always a good idea. Common commands such as *ApplicationCommands.Copy* can be executed by pretty much any control which supports clipboard operations, and knowing which actual control will handle the invocation of such a command requires knowing about how *RoutedCommands* are routed through the visual tree and how the [logcial focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) affects this routing. Thus, sometimes it is
easier to define your own *RoutedCommand* as a public static property - which we will do here for the "*Add*" action:

```
public partial class CRUDDataGrid1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand AddCommand = new RoutedCommand("CRUDDataGridCommand.Add", typeof(CRUDDataGrid1));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandBindings.Add(
            new CommandBinding(
                AddCommand,
                OnExecutedAddCommand,
                CanExecuteAddCommand
            )
        );

        ...other constructor code...
    }

    private void CanExecuteAddCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = ...here your code that decides whether the "Add" command can execute
                       (and thus whether any button which uses this command will be enabled/disabled)
    }

    private void CanExecuteAddCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...execute the "Add" action here...
    }
}
```

Note the command-binding in the constructor as well as the respective methods handling the command. Just to avoid confusion: It is not required that the object serving as *CommandTarget* has to implement command-bindings. *CommandTarget* merely specifies the object in the visual/logical tree at which the routing starts.

While i do not show it here, the implementation regarding the **DeleteCommand** in *UserControl* is following the same pattern.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand DeleteCommand = new RoutedCommand("UserControl1Command.Delete", typeof(UserControl1));

    ...same implementation approach as demonstrated for CRUDDataGrid1.AddCommand...
}
```

Creating the *ToolBar* can now happen entirely in *UserControl1.xaml* without worrying how the respective actions represented by the commands are executed. Note, that it is fine to use *<Button>* since the toolbar is entirely created in UserControl1 without a possibility that any of these buttons could be "shared" with another control. Also, note the absence of those helper classes like *UseCommand* and *MergeCollectionsConverter* which were required for the somewhat convoluted scenario in section 2 of my answer.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1" ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Content="Add" Command="{x:Static local:CRUDDataGrid1.AddCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=cdg}" />
                <Button Content="Delete" Command="{x:Static local:UserControl1.DeleteCommand}" />
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <local:CRUDDataGrid1 x:Name="cdg" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <local:CRUDDataGrid1.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@FirstName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@LastName}" />
            </local:CRUDDataGrid1.Columns>
        </local:CRUDDataGrid1>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**CRUDataGrid1** should probably directly inherit from the DataGrid type (not being a *UserControl*), implementing the extended CRUD functionality as you require.

By letting *CRUDataGrid1* provide only *RoutedCommands* for any desired user-action, you and anybody else in your team is free in the decision where in the GUI to use the *RoutedCommands* - in tool bars, in menus or whereever else. You can use multiple buttons using the same command - no problem there. The infrastructure behind *RoutedCommands* also will take care about automatically enabling/disabling such buttons depending on the result of the *CanExecute* method bound to a command.

In the example given here, i did let *CRUDataGrid1* and *UserControl1* provide the *RoutedCommands*. But if you have many commands and more complex software, then there is nothing speaking against having a central place for defining those commands (similar to what Microsoft did with the *RoutedCommands* provided by the .NET framework).

Comment: Many thanks for your so detailed answer. I know my design is quite-bad because I was writing VBA for Excel only. I am quite new to C# and WPF. But at the present I have no time to re-design my program, so I encapsulate two highly-coupling class -- View and ViewModel into two base classes. Therefore, what I need to do is the modify those two classes. Many thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I already guessed that you would not have much time to spare right now just to redesign your code, that's why i offered two answers.